# How to access the previous route from Durandal router

Tags: durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

Is there a way to access the previous route/instruction from the Durandal.js router? I know I can do `router.navigateBack()` to actually navigate back, but I want to know the route that I will navigating back to before I trigger the navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly I'm afraid.

router.navigateBack() is defined in [router.js](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/platforms/Bower/Durandal/js/plugins/router.js) as

```
    router.navigateBack = function() {
        history.navigateBack();
    };
```

And history.navigateBack() is defined in [history.js](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/platforms/Bower/Durandal/js/plugins/history.js) as

```
    history.navigateBack = function() {
        history.history.back();
    };
```

and history.history is an alias defined above for window.history which is part of the browser and would cause security issues if exposed.

If you want to have that functionality you'll have to implement it yourself.  Possibly by intercepting `router.navigate()` and `router.navigateBack()`.

Comment: That makes sense. I was hoping there was some way for the Durandal router to do some magic there since it's a single page app, but since it's really just implementing the browser history I see that's not possible.

Comment: Yeah I wish it did too.  Btw if you think my answer is the right one please mark it as correct.  Thanks.